# Magento 2 : Discount is added to add to quote, reset to 0.00 when add product

Tags: magento2

I added the discount to quote Programmatically. this is working fine,code below add the discount in quote.

```
<?php
namespace TM\Ar\Model\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class CustomDiscount extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{

    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $_priceCurrency;

    /**
     * Custom constructor.
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param $discount
     */
    public function __construct(
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    ) {
        $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this|bool
     */
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

        $baseDiscount = -89;

        if (!$baseDiscount) {
            return $this;
        }

        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        if ($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping') {
            return $this;
        }


        $discount =  $this->_priceCurrency->convert($baseDiscount);
        $discountAmount = $discount;

        $total->addTotalAmount('customer_discount', -$discount);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal(-$baseDiscount);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Discount is added to quote (-89)

But, when i ade the product, discuont is not calculated,product is added with full price in quote.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give custom discount this way. Invoice totals are calculated with product and shipping prices.

I would suggest using Magento cart price rules. Instead of setting a discount to the price directly during quote, you can create a cart price rule with -89 discount and apply it to your quote programmatically when you create the order like this:

```
$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
$quote->save();
```

Hint: This way the discount appears as a coupon and is shown in your invoice totals with it's respective label.

Comment: let me check that.

Comment: it is not working, it show 0.00 even after adding discount.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have exactly this snippet working well in my own POS Extension.

Comment: it add the discount amount under `coupon_code (89)` column in `quote` table .

Comment: Yea, like I said, if you use coupon codes from the cart price rules, the discount will show in the invoice totals under it's label. So I assume it's working now?

Comment: yes it will, but i am adding quote and its items programmatically from admin side. user will only place order.